# gradually decrement jQuery animate speed per call

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Issue 1:** I would like to animate letters falling to the bottom of a page on hover. I also want to gradually increase the speed at which the letter falls.

I tried doing the following, but it doesn't work:

```
myspan.animate({"top": $(window).outerHeight()}, speed-=1000, "linear", function() {
    $(this).remove(); //remove when animated letter reaches bottom
});
```

Where in the `animate` function could I gradually alter the speed per call?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LpL8K/4/

**Issue 2:** You'll see as the letters fall near the bottom of the page, a scrollbar appears. This shifts the whole page to the left of the screen. How can I not make a scroll bar appear?

**Issue 3:** The letters all appear clumped on top of each other. I've tried `"letter-spacing": "0.9em"` to fix this, but it doesn't help. Why?

Comment: fiddle please jsfiddle

Comment: Check out easings other than linear: http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/ But also note that one `linear` and `swing` work with jQuery only. The rest need jQueryUI.

Comment: @AbdennourToumi I added a fiddle

Comment: @Growler : See last Update

Answer (score 0):

May Be you want something as this :

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/cpQns/1/

```
setTimeout(function(){
                        $(span).animate(spanDimensions[i], 400, !spans[i+1] && function(){
                            p.html(originalContent);    
                        });
                    }, i *i* 50);
```

The code that decrease the speed is timeout= `i*i*50`

if you want the same speed : timeout= `i*50`

if it becomes very slow at the end ,you can use this timeout = `i *(i*10+ 50)` 
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/cpQns/2/

**UPDATE :**

If the Fiddle is such as you've post : 
See this fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/LpL8K/5/

```
if(speed>=speedmax){speed=speedmin}else{speed=speed+500}
```